# How to keep elements from moving and/or resizing when resizing window?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-grid

I understand this question's been asked countless numbers of times and I've looked through them. Okay, I'm currently working on a website, just for personal practice, and am starting out by doing the layout. It has the Boostrap grid system on there, the particular area we're looking at has two col-md-3s and one col-md-6, we're looking at the col-md-6.

Basically I'm pretending to make a site for a business that hosts parties and events etc, as you can obviously tell by the names of the IDs and classes.

As we can see by the screenshots, when I resize my window, the #h1, #EventParagraph and .event within the larger #Events div all get moved and jumbled when I resize my page.

I am trying to achieve either one of two things, make strictly for desktop view and just have not NOT move at all, or make it mobile and tablet-compatible and have the moving and resizing reflect those changes. I would like code solutions for both.

Here are the image results:

**This is what it looks like initially**
[image: This is what it looks like initially]

**Then this is what happened when I pressed the restore down button on my browser**
[image: Then this is what happened when I pressed the restore down button on my browser]
**Then this is what results when I further make my browser smaller**
[image: Then this is what results when I further make my browser smaller]

Here is current code.

**CSS**

```
#Events {
border-color: black; 
border-width: 1px; 
border-style: solid;
height: 300px;
min-width: 90%;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 25px;
overflow: auto;
}

#Party {
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
border-color: black; 
border-width: 1px; 
border-style: solid;
float:right;
margin-right:15px;
margin-top: 65px;
border-radius: 75px;
}

#h1 {
border-color: black; 
border-width: 1px; 
border-style: solid;
height: 50px;
min-width: 300px;
float:left;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-top: 15px;
}

#EventParagraph {
border-color: black; 
border-width: 1px; 
border-style: solid;
height: 150px;
width:330px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-top:70px;
}

.event {
border-color: black; 
border-width: 1px; 
border-style: solid;
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
background-color: white;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.event h1 {
font-family: Friday Night Lights, sans-serif;
height:inherit;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="border-color: black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; height: 350px">
        <div id="SocialMedia">
            khkhkh
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="border-color: black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; height: 350px">
        <div id="Events">
            <div id="h1">
            </div>
            <div id="Party"></div>
            <div id="EventParagraph"></div> 
            <div class="event"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="border-color: black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; height: 350px">
        <div id="SocialMedia">
            khkhkh
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:90%;
    min-height: 900px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#heading,#jumbotron{
    width: inherit;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;

}
#heading{
    background-color: blue;
}

#jumbotron{
    background-color: gray;
    min-height: 150px;
    line-height: 149px;

}
#partyContainer{
    width: inherit;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin:10px auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.partyItem{
    width:30%;
    min-height: 200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left: 25px;

}
#footer{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .partyItem{
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin:0px auto;

   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <div id="heading">
        <h1>Company1</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="jumbotron">
        <h2>Organizing parties for you</h2>
   </div>

   <div id="partyContainer">
        <div class="partyItem">

        </div>
        <div class="partyItem">

        </div>
        <div class="partyItem">

        </div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
    &copy 2017
   </div>
     
</div>
</body>
</html>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

1. I saw that you used the same ID for two div's. ID is unique.
2. You should do all your CSS in the external file

   On the bottom of CSS, you should see @media. This stands for media queries. What I did was first styled the page with some basic css rules, set margines, and aligned these boxes in one row just like you would see on a desktop. The main thing is that I used media query where it says something like this, just to make it simple - "when you reach the 768px apply the following lines of code"
   Then, these boxes are going to be stacked on top of each other, to make it responsive. You should use media queries to take care of your site's responsive side.
   In the  tag, I put the meta tag
   A  viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.
   The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.
   Also, you should use these min-height instead of "height" so for example if you set the "min-height" for container to 100px. This means, container will start at 100px and if there's some content inside of it that pushes container beyond 100px, it will keep growing, it won't be fixed to 100px. I hope this helps, you can put anything you want inside those boxes, I just wanted to point out how you can make them adjust to the screen's size, and which techniques you can use to achieve that.